# Gradle built jar doesn't have dependency to run

Tags: gradle

This is not my first time running into this problem. I'm trying to use Gradle to assemble a .jar file that contains maven dependency inside so that I can just run the program using commands like:

`$ java -mx900m tregexWrapper-1.0.jar NP TaskSentence.txt`

However, given the size of my jar file (3kb), I sense it's unlikely that Gradle included the dependency I wanted.

This is the result: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/trees/tregex/TregexPattern`

Here is my `build.gradle` file and I even explicitly added the dependency to `runtime` but it didn't help.

```
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'application'

    mainClassName = "Entry"

    sourceCompatibility = 1.5
    version = '1.0'

    jar {
        manifest {
           attributes 'Main-Class': 'Entry'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile group: 'commons-cli', name: 'commons-cli', version: '1.2'
        compile group: 'edu.stanford.nlp', name: 'stanford-corenlp', version: '3.3.1'
        runtime(
             [group: 'commons-cli', name: 'commons-cli', version: '1.2'],
             [group: 'edu.stanford.nlp', name: 'stanford-corenlp', version: '3.3.1']
        )
    }

    run {
        if (project.hasProperty('args')) {
            args project.args.split('\\s+')
        }
    }
```

What's causing the problem?

Comment: I think your run command is missing -jar before the tregexWrapper-1.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

I get good results using the sourceSets as below:

```
jar {
  from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
  from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
  from(configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {
      exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
      exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
      exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
  }
}
```

---

Full example:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'

version = '1.0'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile group: 'commons-cli', name: 'commons-cli', version: '1.2'
  compile group: 'edu.stanford.nlp', name: 'stanford-corenlp', version: '3.3.1'
  runtime(
    [group: 'commons-cli', name: 'commons-cli', version: '1.2'],
    [group: 'edu.stanford.nlp', name: 'stanford-corenlp', version: '3.3.1']
  )
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7

mainClassName = "hello.Main"

//task superjar(type: Jar) {
jar {
  from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
  from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
  from(configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {
      exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
      exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
      exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
  }
}

jar.doFirst {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Falkonry Gram',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
                'Built-Date': new Date(),
                'Built-JDK': System.getProperty('java.version'),
                'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}
```

Comment: The first two lines after `jar {` are redundant, and may result in duplicate files. `configurations.compile.collect` should be `configurations.runtime.collect`.

Comment: You can also use gradle fatjar plugin: https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin

Comment: @Opal I guess I'll use fatjar